# Problem with STL Set comparision class

Tags: c++, class, stl, set

I have a set with IDs, for example {3,7,1,5}. I'd like to have 7 before 1, when table[7] < table[1]. I've done it this way:

- I have a class (MyClass1), which has two members: vector table and operator()
- operator() returns true, when table[a] < table[b]
- in another class (MyClass2) i have set < unsigned int, MyClass1 > MySet1
- I use MySet1.insert() inside members of MyClass2

But... seems that an operator() doesn't have access to table, because table[a] or table[b] causes segfault, and table.size() always return 0 (even when table is not empty of course).

What should I do?

Comment: Please Post your source code.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why not just post the (relevant) sections of your code?

Comment: Please post your code. Its nigh on impossible to figure out whats wrong from a narrative..

Comment: Don't post your code. Create a minimal, compilable, _complete_ testcase that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Sounds like to me that your sorting is not valid. The container **must** be imbued with what's known as a Strict Weak Ordering.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T59qgCPY --> operator() doesn't have access to tab -- tab[a] causes segfault and tab.size() returns 0

Comment: Oh, sorry, there should be List.list.insert(a) of course

Comment: @Tomalak: I find this link really useful: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @m333m: That testcase contains gaping holes, like missing functions that you then invoke anyway. And where do you insert elements into the vector?

Comment: "in another class (MyClass2) i have set < unsigned int, MyClass1 > MySet1" I can't even begin to comprehend what you're saying here.

Comment: Ok, I had some time today and wrote a code presenting my (complex...) problem: http://pastebin.com/7qxhaafD ...

Comment: Output: http://pastebin.com/RE3eLWha

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this little sample helps

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

typedef int sortkey_t;
typedef std::map<int, sortkey_t> lookup_t;

struct by_sort_lookup
{
    by_sort_lookup(const lookup_t& table) : _table(table) {}

    bool operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        lookup_t::const_iterator ai = _table.find(a);
        lookup_t::const_iterator bi = _table.find(b);

        if (ai==bi)           return false;
        if (ai==_table.end()) return false; // choose some
        if (bi==_table.end()) return true;  // complementary
        return (ai->second) < (bi->second);
    }
  private:
    const lookup_t& _table;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, sortkey_t> sortkey_by_id;

    sortkey_by_id[1] = 70;
    sortkey_by_id[2] = 60;
    sortkey_by_id[3] = 80;

    //
    std::vector<int> ids;
    ids.push_back(1);
    ids.push_back(3);
    ids.push_back(2);

    std::cout << "before sorting: " << std::endl;
    std::copy(ids.begin(), ids.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\r\n"));

    std::sort(ids.begin(), ids.end(), by_sort_lookup(sortkey_by_id));

    std::cout << "after sorting: " << std::endl;
    std::copy(ids.begin(), ids.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\r\n"));
}
```